# Displaying operational layers in the overview map

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, flex

Does anyone have the code to display an operational layer within the overview map?

Comment: I am not able to get it to work. I will keep after it and watch here.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <!-- possible values for initialstate: open or closed (default) -->
    <initialstate>open</initialstate>
    <!-- by default it will use the same basemap as current main map,
         you can hardcode as below if you wish -->
    <layer label="Demographics" 
           type="tiled"
           url="http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/USA_Median_Household_Income/MapServer"
    />
</configuration>

<!--
    See Overview Map widget documentation at
    http://links.esri.com/overviewmapwidget
-->
```

Comment: I think that would be considered a basemap layer. Not operational layer. I was successful implemnting several basemaps as the overview. Not so with operational layers (i.e. from my own server)

Comment: It's an example showing how to take an operational layer from the main map (default config.xml), and use it in the overview map.  But you might be right, re-reading the question, maybe it's about putting basemaps+ops layer (not just ops layer) in the overviewmap...

Comment: Have you been succesfull with an operational layer from your own server?

Comment: I have modified this overview map widget xml to make ESRI's street map my default base map in the overview window, but I also want to display an operational layer on top of the streets in the overview window

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer
But I considered that it might be an ends to the mean.
Especially if everyone from GSE went there to vote.
Posting on the ESRI Ideas site does have an affect.

[ESRI Web API Ideas](http://ideas.arcgis.com/)

From the documentation linked by Bjorn  "The coordinate system of the overview map layer should be the same as the Viewer base maps."

Comment: @brad-nesom, your link is redirecting me to a login page for salesforce.com, is that what you intended? Or did you mean http://ideas.arcgis.com/ :)

Comment: I was trying to figure out why I was getting that page. I think it had something to do with me being logged in. (which I had just done in order to post and vote on an idea. I fixed the link. Thanks :)

Comment: FYI... ESRI has been having a lot of problems with there proxy pages rerouting to the right locations, I get this all the time when going through the Resources.argis.com sites.

Comment: I am still trying to display an operational layer in the overview map window, but this doesn't seem possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link in the ESRI Flex Viewer forum where I provide a modified overview map code for just that:

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/46886-Displaying-Operational-Layers-in-Overview-map